# Alfresco update action trigger from Add Content Link

Tags: java, javascript, alfresco

I am using alfresco community edition 4.0.e. I create Inbound and update rules on folder.
In rule invokation process i execute my java script and then called my webservice. when i am trying to Add content from explorer update rule also triggering but it's working fine from network drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck "**Modify all properties when this page closes.**"

If you select it, it will in fact trigger an update of metadata.